# QgsVectorDataProvider addFeatures doesn't take attributes

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to add features in empty QgsVectorLayer with `addFeatures`, I got the layers without attribute:

```
def create_features(input_file, wid, hite, focal_lgth):
    features = []
    filename_def = {
        'name': 'filename',
        'type': QVariant.String,
        'length': 50,
        'precision': 0
    }

    field = QgsField()
    field.setName(filename_def['name'])
    field.setType(filename_def['type'])
    field.setPrecision(filename_def['precision'])
    field.setLength(filename_def['length'])
    fields = QgsFields()
    fields.append(field)

    with open(input_file) as file:
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(file.read(1024))
        file.seek(0)  # Rewind.
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        if has_header:
            next(reader)  # Skip header row.
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            feat = QgsFeature(fields, i)
            ----------------------------
            feat.setAttribute("filename", row[0])
            feat.setGeometry(geometry)
            features.append(feat)
    return features

fts = create_features(input, 4000, 3000, 4.3)
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326", "temporary", "memory")
layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(fts)
```

While I printed `fts[i].attribute("filename")` I got the right value.

Comment: you need call `startEditing()`, 'addFeatures()` and after `commitChanges()`

Comment: I tried but still no attribute